# Postgres query execution times very different across local and cloud database

Tags: postgresql

I have a simple postgres query that counts the number of `Record` objects for a given `Database` object:

```
select count(*) from store_record where database_id='a0b0dffb-4e5a-40d7-8f81-d129ffe35bbc';
```

In the local db, the `Record` table has 35 million objects and `Database.id="a0b0dffb-4e5a-40d7-8f81-d129ffe35bbc"` has 11.7 million objects.

In the cloud db, the `Record` table has 39 million objects and `Database.id="a0b0dffb-4e5a-40d7-8f81-d129ffe35bbc"` has ~12 million objects.

The stats are similar but the execution times are very different:

- Local: the query takes 3 seconds
- Cloud: the query takes ~2 min

Here are the query plans for both queries:

**Local**

```
Finalize Aggregate  (cost=849219.70..849219.71 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=2905.165..2915.472 rows=1 loops=1)
  ->  Gather  (cost=849219.58..849219.69 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=2904.858..2915.456 rows=2 loops=1)
        Workers Planned: 1
        Workers Launched: 1
        ->  Partial Aggregate  (cost=848219.58..848219.59 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=2871.121..2871.122 rows=1 loops=2)
              ->  Parallel Seq Scan on store_record  (cost=0.00..831132.87 rows=6834686 width=0) (actual time=55.204..2597.471 rows=5835078 loops=2)
                    Filter: (database_id = 'a0b0dffb-4e5a-40d7-8f81-d129ffe35bbc'::uuid)
                    Rows Removed by Filter: 11665094
Planning Time: 0.765 ms
JIT:
  Functions: 10
"  Options: Inlining true, Optimization true, Expressions true, Deforming true"
"  Timing: Generation 3.757 ms, Inlining 52.540 ms, Optimization 36.494 ms, Emission 19.836 ms, Total 112.626 ms"
Execution Time: 2918.714 ms
```

**Cloud**

```
Finalize Aggregate  (cost=2736538.10..2736538.10 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=126638.968..126675.865 rows=1 loops=1)
  ->  Gather  (cost=2736538.00..2736538.10 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=126638.828..126675.853 rows=2 loops=1)
        Workers Planned: 1
        Workers Launched: 1
        ->  Partial Aggregate  (cost=2735538.00..2735538.00 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=126612.325..126612.326 rows=1 loops=2)
              ->  Parallel Seq Scan on store_record  (cost=0.00..2731015.70 rows=9044601 width=0) (actual time=117.924..126072.782 rows=7658330 loops=2)
                    Filter: (database_id = 'a0b0dffb-4e5a-40d7-8f81-d129ffe35bbc'::uuid)
                    Rows Removed by Filter: 12357700
Planning Time: 5.079 ms
JIT:
  Functions: 10
"  Options: Inlining true, Optimization true, Expressions true, Deforming true"
"  Timing: Generation 1.249 ms, Inlining 153.195 ms, Optimization 45.848 ms, Emission 34.744 ms, Total 235.036 ms"
Execution Time: 126740.456 ms
```

What is causing this massive difference? My goal is to reproduce the slow cloud query locally so I can debug / optimize it.

Comment: What is the difference between their configurations, disk, buffers etc. One db is not the same as the other.

Comment: Where is the best place to view these configurations?

Comment: The obvious answer would be that your cloud database specs suck--probably the IO in particular.  Turn on track_io_timing if it isn't already, then do `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)`.

Comment: You can use pg_settings to get all configuration settings: SELECT * FROM pg_settings; Or use show: SHOW ALL;

Comment: By the way, we avoid queries like this by preparing the answer before the question is even there. Use a trigger to update a table that holds the number of records for each id, and query this table. That should give you (sub-) millisecond response instead of seconds